# get_queryset vs. get_query_set, Django 1.5 vs. 1.6

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-1.5, django-1.6, osqa

**It looks like I have solved the problem by upgrading to Django 1.6. Just curious, what was going on.**

I am trying to integrate [OSQA](http://www.osqa.net/) alongside an existing Django app, and I am encountering some very subtle issues. Just look at that --- this is one PDB session, no multiple inheritance:

```
(Pdb) p type(self.get_query_set())
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
(Pdb) p type(self.get_queryset())
<class 'forum.models.node.NodeQuerySet'>
```

In Django 1.5, the default `django.db.models.Manager` has method `all` (as in `MyModel.objects.all()`) pointing to `get_query_set()` in line `128` of `django/db/models/manager.py`. In Django, 1.6 this same method is pointing to `get_queryset`, since, I guess, `get_query_set` became deprecated. This is line  `133` of the same file, by the way.

Indeed, OSQA is broken in Django 1.5 It fails with 
`*** AttributeError: AttributeError("'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'filter_state'",)`, because in `forum/views/readers.py`, line `207`, it does

`questions = initial.filter_state(deleted=False)`, and there is no such function. In this case, it is passed `Question.objects.all()` as `initial`, but somehow it ends up being `django.db.models.query.QuerySet` instead of 
`forum.models.node.NodeQuerySet`, which does have the required method.

`(Pdb) from forum.models import Question
(Pdb) type(Question.objects.all())
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
(Pdb) type(Question.objects.get_queryset())
<class 'forum.models.node.NodeQuerySet'>
(Pdb) type(Question.objects.get_query_set())
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>`